# Python 3.6 Extract text from .msg files

Tags: python

I'm currently using the module textract (making use of msg-extractor) to get all text content from msg files. But I get some encoding errors for some files which seem to be related to the open issues for textract ([based on the link](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract/issues/107))

Are there other modules I can use to extract text from msg files? I'm using Python 3.6 for my development

Comment: You can try using  third party library like [msg-extractor](https://github.com/mattgwwalker/msg-extractor)

Comment: It's actually leveraging on the msg-extractor module. I've updated my post to reflect this. Apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

You can use extract_msg module for extracting the metadata from the .MSG files as well as the body.

```
import extract_msg
with extract_msg.Message(filepath) as msg:
     msg_body = msg.body
     msg_subject = msg.subject
     print(msg_body)
```